# Disable a button and an event if a form is open

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have two forms. The first form get info from the second form doing it this way:
//First Form

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
        {
            FormConsultaAdvogado fca = new FormConsultaAdvogado();
            fca.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;

            fca.Show();
        }
```

Then, in the second form, I choose what I need to get back to the first form with this:

```
 else if (FormClienteAberto())
        {

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                FormCliente fdil = (FormCliente)Application.OpenForms["FormCliente"];
                fdil.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
                fdil.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

In the seconde form, I also have a funcion that verifies if the first form is open:

```
public bool FormClienteAberto()
    {
      try
        {
            Form fc = Application.OpenForms["FormCliente"];
            return fc != null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

So, my problems are:

1st- I have a button in the 2nd form that, when the first form is open, must be hide

2nd- I have a RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick event that i need to disable too, if the first form is already open, too.

Wish that you guys can help me!!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to determine those two things when the second form is opened, something like the following in the second form's Load event should work:

```
if(FormClienteAberto())
{
    thatButton.Visible = false;
    thatDataGridView.RowHeaderMouseClick -= thatRowHeaderMouseClickEventHandler;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this way, but the button still visible and the event still on too :\

Comment: Are you sure your FormClienteAberto() function returns the correct value?

Comment: Yes, because i get all the correct values to the correct form when i do de if. :|

Comment: OK, I've just resolved the problem. I relocate to the Form_Load with a if(FormClienteAberto()) and it is working now!
Thank you GeorgeT :D